# Jenkins: Let a job wait while another job is running

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a set of components, one being the base component (A) and all others (B1 .. Bn) being dependent on the base component.

I have Jenkins jobs for each component which are triggered by SCM changes on the respective repositories. Now I would like to configure that a job of a Bx component waits if the base component A is currently building in order to have the latest build of A incorporated in its own build.

I looked at "throttle concurrent builds" plugin but I think I cannot use it in this case. Also I found code snippets to detect if another specific job is running. But then, how do I let the current job wait until the other is finished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Build Blocker](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin) plugin, it does exactly what you need: you can specify job name of `A` component in `Blocking jobs` section for every job of `Bx` components.

Comment: Indeed it looks like it is what I need. Unfortunately I did not yet find out how to use it in a declarative Jenkinsfile. Nevertheless accept you answer as correct.

Comment: Oh, it is part of the General section, so has to be set in the job before the Pipeline section.

Comment: So I think that it is still suitable for your task :)

Comment: Yes, just had to figure out how to set the settings in a DSL job. Solution is https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/freeStyleJob-blockOn